# If $f$ is convex on an open interval $(0, 1)$, then $f$ is continuous on $(0, 1)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-writing

I am having a little bit of trouble with this question but I think I may have the general idea, so I would like some insight on how I should proceed.

> If $f$ is convex on an open interval $(0, 1)$, then $f$ is continuous on $(0, 1)$

Attempt:

We will proceed by contradiction. Let's assume that $f$ is a convex function on $(0, 1)$. Let's also assume (for the sake of contradiction), that $f$ is *not* continuous at some $a \in (0, 1)$. Then this implies that $\exists \varepsilon > 0 \forall \delta > 0 \exists x$ such that $|x - a| < \delta$ but $|f(x) - f(a)| \geq \varepsilon$. Then we shall consider the following cases.

- $|x - a| < \delta$ but $f(x) \geq f(a) + \varepsilon$
- $|x - a| < \delta$ but $f(x) \geq f(a) - \varepsilon$

This is the point where I am not sure how to proceed with this proof. Some advice would be helpful.

Comment: Your second option must be $f(x)\le f(a)-\varepsilon$.

Comment: Here's a [PDF](https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/5210/notes/6-6.pdf) that proves this exactly the way that I would. I would use the three slope lemma (called the "chordal slope lemma" in this PDF) to establish that the left and right derivatives exist, which couldn't possibly exist if the function weren't (left and right) continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Try to show that the fraction $\frac{f(x +t) - f(x)}{t}$ is bounded when $ t \in (- \delta , \delta)$ for a sufficiently small $\delta >0. $